# How to ignore unnecessary attributes in my response.xpath?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to scrape some data with scrapy using xpath selectors and i would like to get rid of the unnecessary data, the xpath selector is the following:

```
values = response.xpath ('//table[@class="pd-table"]//tbody//tr//td/text()').getall()
```

I know with `.getall` I can extract all data from the selector, which gives me the list below (I have added line breaks to make the list more readable - there are no line breaks in the actual output):

```
['Electrical design', 'PNP', 'Output function', 'normally open', 
 'Sensing range [mm]', '4', 'Housing', 'threaded type', 
 'Dimensions [mm]', 'M12 x 1 / L = 60', 
 'Special feature', 'Gold-plated contacts; Increased sensing range',  
 'Application', 'Industrial applications / factory automation', 
 'Operating voltage [V]', '10...30 DC', 'Current consumption [mA]', '< 10', 
 'Protection class', 'III', 'Reverse polarity protection', 'yes', 
'Electrical design', 'PNP', 'Output function', 'normally open', 
 'Max. voltage drop switching output DC [V]', '2.5', 
 'Permanent current rating of switching output DC [mA]', '100', 
 'Switching frequency DC [Hz]', '700', 'Short-circuit protection', 'yes', 
 'Overload protection', 'yes', 'Sensing range [mm]', '4', 
 'Real sensing range Sr [mm]', '4 ± 10 %', 'Operating distance [mm]', '0...3.24', 
 'Increased sensing range', 'yes', 
 'Correction factor', 'steel: 1 / stainless steel: 0.7 / brass: 0.5 / aluminium: 0.4 / copper: 0.3', 'Hysteresis [% of Sr]', '3...15', 
 'Switch point drift [% of Sr]', '-10...10', 
 'Ambient temperature [°C]', '-40...85', 
 'Protection', 'IP 65; IP 66; IP 67; IP 68; IP 69K', 
 'EMC', '\n                        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'EN 61000-4-2 ESD', '4 kV CD / 8 kV AD', 'EN 61000-4-3 HF radiated', '10 V/m', 
 'EN 61000-4-4 Burst', '2 kV', 'EN 61000-4-6 HF conducted', '10 V', 'EN 55011', 'class B', 
 '\n', 'Vibration resistance', '\n                        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'EN 60068-2-6 Fc', '20 g (10...3000 Hz) / 50 sweep cycles, 1 octave per minute, in 3 axes', 
 '\n', 'Shock resistance', '\n                        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'EN 60068-2-27 Ea', '100 g 11 ms half-sine; 3 shocks each in every direction of the 3 coordinate axes', 
 '\n', 'Continuous shock resistance', '\n                        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'EN 60068-2-27', '40 g 6 ms; 4000 shocks each in every direction of the 3 coordinate axes', 
 '\n', 'Fast temperature change', '\n                        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'EN 60068-2-14 Na', 'TA = -40 °C; TB = 85 °C; t1 = 30 min; t2 = < 10 s; 50 cycles', 
 '\n', 'Salt spray test', '\n
\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'EN 60068-2-52 Kb', 'severity level 5 (4 test cycles)', '\n', 
 'MTTF [years]', '1642', 'UL approval', '\n                        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'UL Approval no.', 'A001 ', '\n', 'Weight [g]', '27.7', 
 'Housing', 'threaded type', 'Mounting', 'flush mountable', 
 'Dimensions [mm]', 'M12 x 1 / L = 60', 
 'Thread designation', 'M12 x 1', 
 'Materials', 'brass white bronze coated; sensing face: PBT orange; LED window: PEI; lock nuts: brass white bronze coated', 
 'Display', '\n      
                  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'switching status', '4 x LED, yellow', '\n', 
 'Items supplied', '\n     
                   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', 
 'lock nuts: 2', '\n', 'Pack quantity', '1 pcs.', 
 'Connection', 'Connector: 1 x M12; Contacts: gold-plated']
```

Within the list, each pair of data is equivalent to 1 Element which I want to format similarly to the sample below:

```
['Electrical design' : 'PNP', 
'Output function' : 'normally open
....

'EMC' : 'EN 61000-4-2 ESD' : '4 kV CD / 8 kV AD' , 'EN 61000-4-3 HF radiated' : '10 V/m', 
...
'Connector: 1 x M12 : Contacts: gold-plated']
```

I hope I was able to explain myself clearly. I need help to transform the raw data to a formatted list.

Comment: Please format your question. Also, `['Electrical design' : 'PNP', 'Output function' : 'normally open` looks like a dictionary data structure (bacause of `:`), but you include `[` (which points to a list) there, so it's a bit confusing what you really want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to these forums....
Using Scrapy and Xpath selectors I can get data from a specific website with no problems. The problem is the formatting of the data. So I get the string I copied with some data inside that I don't need ('\n) . I would like to remove those elements and put information inside those removed elements which are the ones that come after those spaces and my example that I would like to get is an object ['Electrical Design' : 'PNP' , 'Output function' : 'normally open', .......]

Comment: Is there anything in the Scrapy documentation that will help you? (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html). It should be possible to adjust the code you're using to retrieve the data to get it formatted the way you want - if you could edit your post to tell us what language you're using to retrieve the data and the HTML of the section you're scraping it would help us to help you.